# CGPoint as a property

Tags: ios, xcode, properties

I've been trying to avoid using iVars for many reasons, and use property instead.

If I set up as a property variable such as `CGPoint` type:

```
@interface Foo () {

    @property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint lastPoint;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
Expression is not assignable
```

I understand that `CGRect`, `CGPoint` etc kind of structs and that's why it doesn't work.
And of course I can use `_lastPoint` to solve that.

I'm assuming that I have to create custom setter? But... probably it's impossible or redundant.

I would like to have something like:

```
self.lastPoin.x = 10;
```

Comment: Just try as @property (nonatomic) CGPoint lastPoint;

Comment: doesn't make sense...

Comment: Adding @interface Foo () {@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint lastPoint;} is not possible.

Comment: @Natarajan Yes it is. Why do you say it isn't?

Comment: @rmaddy Will objectiveC allows you to set "@property" inside of brace?

Comment: @Natarajan Sorry, it's very late for me. You are correct. The property should not be in curly braces. I was more focused on the property definition itself, not where it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cann't assign like this `self.lastPoint.x = 10;` But you can assign like `self.lastPoint = CGPointMake(10, 0);`. Because setter method is only available for `lastPoint`, not for `lastPoint.x`. Because you already know, lastPoint is an struct. If you want to like this assign, you can for for instance variable like

```
@interface Foo () {

    CGPoint lastPoint;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the properties, you are using the setter methods. CGPoint is having two iVars like x and y. They are not declared as properties.

So, either you can set the point directly because you have created property for it or you can directly assign value to x and y by accessing point directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble with `self.lastPoint.x = 10;`.

Remember, this is the same as `[self lastPoint].x = 10;`.

What you need to do is the following:

```
CGPoint point = self.lastPoint;
point.x = 10;
self.lastPoint = point;
```